# Can't count multiple columns

Tags: sql, where-clause, countif

My code is

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS none 
FROM 
    college_votes 
WHERE 
    `bd` IN ('none', '-Select for Board of Director-') 
    AND `bd1` IN ('none', '-Select for Board of Director-') 
    AND `bd2` IN ('none', '-Select for Board of Director-') 
    AND `bd3` IN ('none', '-Select for Board of Director-')
```

I want to count the same value in different columns

Comment: share sample data and expected output , it will help you to get solution faster

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of id

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS none FROM college_votes ...
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can apply `conditional aggregation` with `SUM` for all four columns :*

```
SELECT 
      SUM(CASE WHEN `bd`  IN ('none', '-Select for Board of Director-') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
      AS number_of_bd,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `bd1` IN ('none', '-Select for Board of Director-') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
      AS number_of_bd1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `bd2` IN ('none', '-Select for Board of Director-') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
      AS number_of_bd2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `bd3` IN ('none', '-Select for Board of Director-') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
      AS number_of_bd3
 FROM college_votes;
```

Comment: @user10242846 yes, you need to.

Comment: But How, they are all seperated how to make them in one